# How to minify a JS file but retain all handlebars mustaches

Tags: javascript, babeljs, minify

I need to minify something but retain all handlebars mustaches. I can't find any library or plugins that seem to accomplish this.

I understand I *should* populate the handlebars with values first, but it's not possible for this project.

Comment: You mean curly brackets?

Comment: A minifier shouldn't change the semantic meaning of the javascript file. If it did, it's broken... perhaps you can share a bit more about what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I have a js file with a ton of long functions and objects. Some of the objects have things like

`var foo = {
  animals: {
       {{#each Zoo.animals}
       '{{@key}}': {
         found: true
       }{{#unless @last}},{{/unless}}
         {{/each}}
     }
}`

with that, the {{#each}} breaks it, since its not valid js (which is fine, because it turns valid after its populated with the handlebars stuff}